# how to modify contacts.db and Import 160,000 contacts to android phone

Tags: android, contacts, root

I have about 160,000 contacts, I need to import them to my phone. how Can I do this by modifying contacts.db in a rooted android

i have tried importing using the phones contact app, but it fails, I have tried importing using google contacts but it is slow (4k per Gmail account) and breaks

Comment: I would start with a clean database, manually add/import two or three contacts, reboot the phone, extract the db file and then dump it to SQL. Then read the SQL dump and compare it to the imported contacts and you see how the contacts db is structured.

Answer (score 0):

> I would start with a clean database, manually add/import two or three
> contacts, reboot the phone, extract the db file and then dump it to
> SQL. Then read the SQL dump and compare it to the imported contacts
> and you see how the contacts db is structured. –  Robert

To add to this further, if you have a rooted device and the database file, then I highly recommend DB Browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/). I've used it many times to view and modify SQLite databases